# Application integrity & url tampering

Tags: security

On my site people can ask questions and answers can be posted. The question is at example.com/question/title. To post an answer, the form is submitted to example.com/question/post_answer/7 with 7 being the question id.

Validation is run here to make sure an answer was entered. If not, it takes you back to the original url. So the post_answer path is never actually 'seen' by users but they can obviously access it.

I'm wondering now that if a user changes the id of the question to 8, he could post an answer to another question.

This isn't *really* a security issue since all users would achieve is answering another question. But I'm wondering - in a scenario like this, how do you stop that kind of url tampering: storing the question id in the session and showing an error if it gets changed?

Thoughts?

Comment: If you can store the question id in the session there is no need to hand it to the user at all. Then this kind of attack doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are one way. Another one would be to use some kind of a message authentication code (MAC). Typically you'd use [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) and store the code in a cookie or a part of the URL (i.e. a GET parameter).